# Вопрос по редактированию ширины страницы в HTML

Tags: html, вёрстка

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы ширина страницы, собственно, фон и все что на нем, на любом экране и в любом браузере была фиксированной ширины?
Например 1280px?

Comment: @Palmervan, да мало того, что он вопросы плодит, так он ещё "тридцать три" аккаунта сделал. По приколу, что ли...

Answer (score 1):

```
body {
  width: 1280;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Добавьте пояснения. Опишите, на чем основан ваш ответ.

Comment: Этого ответа достаточно.

Answer (score 0):

берешь в div блоки и в css файле задаешь ширину и высоту)